# Trying to use remote field validation

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, validation

I'm just trying to make this work for the first time:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg508808%28v=vs.98%29.aspx

In my model I have

```
    [Remote("RequireName", "Contact")]
    [Editable(true)]
    public string Name { get; set; }
```

In my controller I have

```
public JsonResult RequireName(string Name)
    {
        bool resultbool = ((Name != null) && (Name.Length > 0));
        return this.Json(resultbool ? "OK." : "Not OK.", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

(I don't care about it's result message for now.)

In my resulting HTML I have:

```
<input type="text" value="" name="Name" id="Name" data-val-remote-url="/[mysite]/Contact/RequireName" data-val-remote-additionalfields="*.Name" data-val-remote="'Name' is invalid." data-val="true" class="text-box single-line">
```

URL http://localhost/[mysite]/Contact/RequireName
returns "Not OK.", which is correct.
URL http://localhost/[mysite]/Contact/RequireName?Name=something
returns "OK.", which is correct.

But when I edit the field or even when I submit the complete form, validation does not happen.
I'm sure I'm missing something. Thank you if you can help me.

Comment: In my experience, the most common cause of client-side validation errors is due to missing javascript references. Can you view-source on the form and post the generated HTML?

Comment: Also, another common issue is that `ClientValidationEnabled` and `UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled` is not enabled in web.config - have you checked that? (This is described in step 3 in section "Examining the Validation Code" given in the MSDN article that you reference.)

Comment: Both ClientValidationEnabled and UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled are enable and I have no special javascript inclusion and I don't that javascript inclusions are mentionned by the tutorial I've followed and linked.

Comment: I forgot to mentiong but standard validation such are [StringLength(6, MinimumLength = 3)] or [Required] work fine when I submit the complet form (not field by field), it's apparently only the [Remote ...] validation type the doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

After some more Internet search, I understood that I had to include "jquery.validate.min.js" and "jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js". Sounds basics but I had not clue about it yet.